# How can I remove a specific table row after the fancybox dialog closes?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here's my code for calling the fancybox dialog:

```
$('.btnUpdateitem').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
});
```

Here's my code for removing a specific table row:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

But my table is based on ajax result:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what context $(this) should refer to, so:

In the right context

```
$cachedClosest = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Calling fancybox

```
$('.btnUpdateitem').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
afterClose: function() {
    $cachedClosest.remove();
  })
});
```

Hope it helps a little